# Compare similarities between two data frames using more than one column in each data frame

Tags: pandas

This work started by comparing two columns in each data set in pandas.
Previous research:[here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33053/how-do-i-compare-columns-in-different-data-frames/33062#33062)

A lot of results online show how to compare 2 data frames with 1 column
I'm trying to learn how to compare and extract similarities between two data frames (same & different sizes if possible) using more than 1 column in pandas.
sample input:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,None],[1,None,],[1,None],[1,'item_a'],[2,'item_a'],[2,'item_b'],[2,'item_f'],[3,'item_e'],[3,'item_e'],[3,'item_g'],[3,'item_h']],columns=['id','A'])
df2=pd.DataFrame([[1,'item_a'],[1,'item_b'],[1,'item_c'],[1,'item_d'],[2,'item_a'],[2,'item_b'],[2,'item_c'],[2,'item_d'],[3,'item_e'],[3,'item_f'],[3,'item_g'],[3,'item_h']],columns=['id','A'])
```

```
 df1
        id  A
    0   1   None
    1   1   None
    2   1   None
    3   1   item_a
    4   2   item_a
    5   2   item_b
    6   2   item_f
    7   3   item_e
    8   3   item_e
    9   3   item_g
    10  3   item_h
```

```
df2
    id  A
0   1   item_a
1   1   item_b
2   1   item_c
3   1   item_d
4   2   item_a
5   2   item_b
6   2   item_c
7   2   item_d
8   3   item_e
9   3   item_f
10  3   item_g
11  3   item_h
```

What I've tried  so far:

```
   1: df1[df1.A.isin(df2.A) & df1.id.isin(df2.id)]

   2: df1[   df1[['id', 'A']].isin(df2[['id', 'A']])  ]
```

The output I got for 1 is close to what I desire:

```
    id  A
3   1   item_a
4   2   item_a
5   2   item_b
6   2   item_f #this specific row is not desired in the output
7   3   item_e
8   3   item_e #this specific row was raised due to a duplicate in `df1`. It's permitted to show duplicates. Duplicates values are allowed in `df1` but not `df2`.
9   3   item_g
10  3   item_h
```

Desired output:

```
    id  A
3   1   item_a
4   2   item_a
5   2   item_b
7   3   item_e
8   3   item_e
9   3   item_g
10  3   item_h
```

What's not shown: Two data frames have 2500+ rows. df1 can have the same items associated with an id. No duplicate items for an id in df2.
My 2nd try `2: df1[   df1[['id', 'A']].isin(df2[['id', 'A']])  ]` is definitely the wrong approach as its matching row and column in `df1` to row and column `df2` (This output is similar to `equals()`, I get values from `df1` instead of True and NaN instead of False)
Any code, links, suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Required DataFrame]

[image: Data Frame side by side]

The **last df** is your required result, **2nd last** is mine.
I think **3, item_f** is not possible as its absent in df1.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense if I put 3,item_e  instead of 3,item_f. So, I've edited the question according to your answer.